# SSO with persona multiple sites

Tags: single-sign-on, persona

anybody know is possible to use Persona for SSO purposes for cross site login, where each site is it's own domain?  Very similar to 37signals and how they set up basecamp, Highrise and campfire.

Would like to have user create something similar to a 37 signals ID.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If all of your sites share a common domain (e.g. `foo.example.com` and `bar.example.com`) then you could have a login server (say `login.example.com`) that sets an `example.com`-wide cookie that each subdomain can use.

For cross-domain sites, there has been a [realm proposal](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/mozilla.dev.identity/z3d_wj6Jjq0/discussion) but it's not currently being worked on.